# Thymeleaf th:if with th:each on the same html element

Tags: thymeleaf

I am generating all menu link dynamically using Thymeleaf. I have written code which is working fine.

```
    <ul>
         <li th:each="menu : ${menus}"><a href='#'><span th:text="${menu}">Home</span></a></li>
   </ul>
```

My question is, how can I add a class (activeMenu) on li element if menu's value is equal to Home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would insert this part in the element that you want to insert specific class, in your case span element:

```
th:class="${menu}=='Home' ? activeMenu"
```

or:

```
th:class="${menu}=='Home' ? activeMenu:''"
```

it should work like this:

```
<ul>
    <li th:each="menu : ${menus}"><a href='#'><span th:class="${menu}=='Home' ? activeMenu:''">th:text="${menu}">Home</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

I have not tried this specific condition, but it should work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i have to add class on the li element.

Comment: well, try using th:class on the li element?